# how to get the class name of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

how to get the class name of divs?

```
<body>
    <a id="append">Add DIV</a> 
    <div id="parent"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var count = 0;
          $('#append').click(function() {
            $('#parent').append('<div
                class="article' + count + '">im div</div>');
            count++;
          });
          $('div').click(function() {
            alert(this.class);
          });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

when i am trying to display class name of divs in alert it shows undefind.

Comment: you dont have class in the html

Comment: use event delegation like `$(document).on('click','div',function(){` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Event delegation heres the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0sptau59/)

```
$('#parent').on('click','div',function() {
className = $(this).attr('class');
    alert(className);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an attr property:

```
$(this).attr('class');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Example Of Your Question

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($('#ss').attr('class'));
});
```

```css
.ssclass{
width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background:#ff8800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ss" class="ssclass"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('#append').click(function() {
    $('#parent').append('<div class="article' + count + '">im div</div>');
    count++;
  });
  $('div').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('class'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a id="append">Add DIV</a> 
  <div class='className' id="parent"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **event delegation** for dynamically created elements. Otherwise your class not triggered on click.

```
$('#parent').on('click', 'div', function() {
  var getclass = $(this).attr('class');
  console.log(getclass);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently what you are using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach to element that exist on the page at the time your code makes the event binding call. As you are generating elements dynamically, You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach.

*General Syntax*

```
$(document).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Additionally, You need to read `className` property or use [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $('#append').click(function() {
    $('#parent').append('<div class="article' + count + '" > im div </div>');
    count++;
  });
  $('#parent').on('click', "div", function() {
    alert(this.className)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="append">Add DIV</a> 
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how you can get the all the `class name` of div's. refer the working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">




</style>


<body>

<div class="main">
 <div class="classone">my name is class one</div>
 <div class="classtwo">my name is class two</div>
 <div class="classthree">my name is class three</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var thelength = $("div.main div").length;//get how many divs
 for(var i=0;i<thelength;i++)
 {
  var theclass_name = $("div.main div").eq(i).attr('class');//get the class name of each.
  alert(theclass_name);
 }
});

</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it

```
 <body> 
  <a id="append">Add DIV</a> 
  <div id="parent"></div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      var count = 0; 
      $('#append').click(function(){    
        $('#parent').append('<div class="article'+count+'">im div</div>'); count++; 
      }); 
      $('#parent div').click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('class'));  
      }); 
    }); 
  </script>
</body>
```